# How to get Shipping Methods custom additional data in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, settings, shipping-method

From this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60041709/5412773) I've created custom field "Shipping Method Description" inside shipping methods:

```php7
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'shipping_instance_form_fields_filters');

function shipping_instance_form_fields_filters(){
    $shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();
    foreach($shipping_methods as $shipping_method) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_instance_form_fields_' . $shipping_method->id, 'shipping_instance_form_add_extra_fields');
    }
}

function shipping_instance_form_add_extra_fields( $settings ){
    $settings['shipping_method_description'] = [
        'title'       => 'Shipping Method Description',
        'type'        => 'text', 
        'placeholder' => 'shipping',
        'description' => ''
    ];

    return $settings;
}
```

But I can't understand how to get this data in front-end inside my custom shipping template(/cart/cart-shipping.php) like:

```php7
<?php if ( $available_methods ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?>

        <p><?php /* Method Description ??? */ ?></p>

        <p><?= $method->get_label(); ?></p>
        <p><?= $method->cost; ?></p>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64064609/5412773) isn't clear for me how to get this instance settings.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WooCommerce shipping method settings are stored in `wp_options` table on `option_name` column as follows *(where `$methods_id` is name (slug) and `$instance_id` the numerical identifier)*:

```
 $option_name = 'woocommerce_' . $methods_id . '_' . $instance_id . '_settings';
```

To get that shipping method settings (array) you can use WordPress `get_option()` function like:

```
<?php 
if ( $available_methods ) {
    foreach ( $available_methods as $rate ) {
        $data = get_option( 'woocommerce_' . $rate->method_id . '_' . $rate->instance_id . '_settings' ); 

        if ( isset($data['shipping_method_description']) ) {
            echo '<p>' . $data['shipping_method_description'] . '</p>';
        }
        echo '<p>' . $rate->label . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $rate->cost . '</p>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Tested and works.